# Http-request not through proxy cache (tor + privoxy + squid)

Tags: caching, proxy, squid, tor, proxy-server

I create one proxy cache using (tor + privoxy + squid) follow

[How to create an advanced proxy server using Tor, Privoxy, and Squid](http://mightycomputers.wordpress.com/2012/09/10/recently-i-foun/)

I try call to Proxy cache

```
curl -x 'my-ip:3400' -I 'https://github.global.ssl.fastly.net/images/modules/dashboard/bootcamp/octocat_setup.png'
curl -x 'my-ip:3400' -I http://hadoop.apache.org/images/hadoop-logo.jpg
```

https request is ok (through Pivoxy)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
Proxy-Agent: Privoxy/3.0.21

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 08 Mar 2014 04:38:37 GMT
Server: GitHub.com
Content-Type: image/png
Last-Modified: Fri, 16 Aug 2013 09:42:18 GMT
Expires: Sun, 08 Mar 2015 04:38:37 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, public
Timing-Allow-Origin: https://github.com
Content-Length: 10722
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Via: 1.1 varnish
Age: 0
X-Served-By: cache-am72-AMS
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0
X-Timer: S1394253517.449177980,VS0,VE97
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

but http requets not working

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Sat, 08 Mar 2014 04:39:19 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.8-dev (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 OpenSSL/1.0.1e
Last-Modified: Tue, 12 Feb 2008 17:38:57 GMT
ETag: "24e3-445f987fe69d8"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 9443
Content-Type: image/jpeg
X-Cache: MISS from SVR226L-696.localdomain
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from SVR226L-696.localdomain:3128
Via: 1.0 SVR226L-696.localdomain (squid)
Connection: keep-alive
```

Please suggest a specific solution